# How to induce some template classes being united by one template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have some template classes. They are united by one namespace, and really they depends on each other's template parameter.

That is a good point for using #define T instead of template, and use in all classes, but client for those classes may want create some such pairs with different T, that is why I want to use templates.

But if I create just two separated classes with their own separated templates, I have good chance that client will make mistake and will put different values there. So, I would like to avoid it, if it is possible, to make set T once for pair of such classes and use both classes with it's value.

I would like to create something like that (just imagine):

```
template<int T>
namespace Sample
{
    struct A
    {
        char _data[T];
    }

    struct B
    {
        void Get(A& a)
        {
            memcpy(b, a._data, T);
        }
        char b[T];
    }
}
```

So, there are separated classes, but if one has parameter T = 50, then other have to work with same parameter. Best solution - template namespace, but C++ has no template namespaces.

Is it possible to make it somehow? Maybe I need any pattern?

I don't want to add something like:

```
char X1[T1 - T2 + 1];
char X2[T2 - T1 + 1];
```

Inside class B, to get error if T1 != T2 at compilation, I would like to find simple and beauty solution for that task, I believe it have to exist :-)

Comment: Thank you for reply, but yes, that is not what I wanted, I changed example to avoid such solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested classes. Simply replace `namespace` with `struct`.

```
template<int T>
struct Sample {
    struct A {
        char _data[T];
    };

    struct B{
        // ...
    };

    // You can have static methods that operate on types from
    // the same template instance without specifying the type
    static void foo(B& b) {
        A a{0};
        b.Get(a);
    }
};

int main() {
    Sample<2>::A a{0};
    Sample<2>::B b;
    b.Get(a);
}
```

Perhaps remove the constructor of `Sample` so no one tries to instantiate it.

Comment: Thank you. But inside I have enum class Type : LONG32 { TypeA = 1}, and now compiler tells that dependant name can't be type. Is it possible to solve using this idea?

Comment: There should be no problem with having enum classes inside. What sort of type is `LONG32`?

Comment: it is "signed int". It wanted "typename" prefix to indicate that is a type, I just didn't knew it is allowed to put it in function parameters. Everything works!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this is a problem. The following code already will not compile due to different values being used for the respective `T` parameters:

```
template <int T>
struct A
{
};

template <int T>
struct B
{
    Get(A<T>& a) {}
};

int main()
{
    A<5> a;
    B<10> b;
    b.Get(a); // cannot convert A<5> to A<10>&
}
```

Comment: +1 I answered to the question but what was asked doesn't really have advantages to having separate templates.